# The JS cannot refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I  have a php file named angularGaugeChart.php. It will display a chart by using "plot.ly" library. When first visit it by browser, it can display the chart correctly. I want to it refresh automatically. Thus, I added following script. The php can refresh automatically, but it cannot display the chart after refreshment. I want to know what is the problem in it?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

    <div id="solarRad" style="width:500px;height:400px;">
        <?php 
        include 'SQL.php';

        mysql_select_db($dbname);

        $sqlSolarRad="SELECT * FROM `Test` order by date DESC, time DESC limit 1 ";
        $restsqlSolarRad=mysql_query($sqlSolarRad);
        while($rowsSqlSolarRad=mysql_fetch_array($restsqlSolarRad))
        {
            $lastRecordSolarRad= $rowsSqlSolarRad['solarRad'];
        }

        ?>  

        <script>
            var dataSolarRad = [
            {
                domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
                value: <?php echo $lastRecordSolarRad ?>,
                title: { text: "Solar Radiation (W/m²)" },
                type: "indicator",
                mode: "gauge+number",
                delta: { reference: 400 },
                gauge: { axis: { range: [null, 1366] } }
            }
            ];

            var layout = { width: 700, height: 400};
            Plotly.newPlot('solarRad', dataSolarRad, layout);
        </script>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onload = setupRefresh();
        function setupRefresh()
        {
            setInterval("refreshBlock();",10000);
        }

        function refreshBlock()
        {
            $("#solarRad").load("angularGaugeChart.php #solarRad");
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I press the refresh button in the browser, the php can display the chart correctly.

Comment: I think turning `setInterval("refreshBlock();",10000);` into `setInterval(refreshBlock,10000);` should do the trick but it would be worse looking into your console to check whether there are other javascript errors...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @LaurentS. No. the functionality of the two versions are the same - just the "" makes it an "eval"

Comment: HOWEVER the `document.onload = setupRefresh();` is certainly wrong and should be `document.onload = setupRefresh`

Comment: what will be the response when requesting  `angularGaugeChart.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.onload = setupRefresh();` is wrong and should be `document.onload = setupRefresh;`
2. It is not recommended to quote a function in a setInterval/Timeout - instead use `setInterval(refreshBlock,10000);` HOWEVER
3. You load and use jQuery, so USE it!!! Also bust the cache

---

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#solarRad").load("angularGaugeChart.php?rdn="+new Date().getTime()+" #solarRad");
  },10000) 
})
```

Why not use a simpler AJAX?

```
$.get("getLastRecordSolarRad.php?rdn="+new Date().getTime(),function(lastRecordSolarRad) {
  var dataSolarRad = [{
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: lastRecordSolarRad,
    title: { text: "Solar Radiation (W/m²)" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number",
    delta: { reference: 400 },
    gauge: { axis: { range: [null, 1366] } }
  }];
  var layout = { width: 700, height: 400};
  Plotly.newPlot('solarRad', dataSolarRad, layout);
});
```

Comment: Same result also, After auto refreshment, nothing display in the webpage.

Comment: I think it is the problem of "plot.ly" library. If I included following code in the refreshment : Plotly.newPlot('solarRad', dataSolarRad, layout); the white screen will display after auto refresh.